# Question about graphing the clusters in K means

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, k-means

I've used K means to cluster my data. Before using K means, I had used StandardScaler on my data to standardize the data. Now, I'm wondering how can I show the clusters of the original data. Scikit-learn gives the labels on the standardized data but I want to have the labels on the original data and show the clusters of the original data on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

StandardScaler subtracts the mean from each variable and then divides it by the standard deviation. It's a common preprocessing step, certainly for k-means because this algorithm heavily depends on the scaling of the data.

If I understand correctly you want to visualize the original data and make use of the labels from k-means by doing so. You could either add the labels to the original data (assuming the order of the records did not change):

```
original_with_label = numpy.concatenate(original, labels, axis = 1)
```

Or you could transform the data back to its original scale:

```
transformed_back_to_original = scalar_fit.inverse_transform(transformed_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Keep and access the original data (e.g. by index) - recompute the means.

Option 2:

Apply the inverse transformation. StandardScaler is a linear transformation, so its reversible up to some loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://www.pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/) is a really good tutorial for you to consider.

Towards the end, the author shows you how to map the index back to the cluster IDs.

```
details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(returns.index,idx)]

for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```